Rotating a 2D polygon to always face camera in 3D space
I'm adding arrowed lines on a mesh in PyVista. I want the surface of lines to always face the camera without changing it's starting and ending axis.


When I add the arrowed line polygon, it's surface is faced towards top camera view. It looks perfectly fine if I want to see it from top, but I want it to rotate it so that the surface is visible from even the side or front. Otherwise it becomes a single pixel and is unviewable. Any hints or guidance will be preferred, Thank You!

Hi. It's a bit unclear what exactly it is that you need help with. How are you manipulating this arrow? Do you manipulate the list of its vertices and are looking for the mathematical formula to rotate the polygon? Or is it represented as a specific pyvista object and you are looking for the pyvista parameter or method to rotate it? What is it that you have and what is it that you're lacking?

@Stef I first pick starting and ending points by clicking in mesh, and then calculate the arrows and lines and then add them to polydata which is then used in vtkActor. What I have is only poly data and position of camera, I've manually tried to change the orientation of the actor to adjust the view and it works but I want to achieve that automatically. Thank you for your response

@Stef What I'm manipulating is orientation of the polygon, what I have is vertices and active camera and what I lack is orientation where I can see the polygon properly. I need a mathematical formula to calculate the new vertices of polygon at every camera angle.
